# HTML & CSS: ">" Greater than selector styles not applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i am facing a very strange problem. From what i understand by the CSS ">" than selector is that it basically applies style to the direct childs only. But i am not able to get the styles applied to the elements at all. What's strange is while inspecting the elements i can see the other CSS part in firebug but i can't see the ">" styles applied.

HTML i have is :

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS part is this:

```
/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    min-height:45px;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 45px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #F3F3F3;
}

#navigation ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#navigation > ul > li {
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation > ul > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 18px 13px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#navigation > ul > li.current_page_item > a, 
#navigation > ul > li.current_page_parent > a, 
#navigation > ul > li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    border-top: 3px solid #72AC4B;
    color: #72AC4B;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

all other style is being applied as it normally would, but the style blocks that use ">" selector are not being recognized at all. So say suppose if i inspect the `li` element, i am able to see the following style applied:

```
#navigation ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

But i can't see the following style applied:

```
#navigation > ul > li {
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
}
```

even though it is a direct child of the ul. Has anyone faced this problem before ? What might be causing this ?

Comment: I have tested this with chrome and firefox and i have `<!DOCTYPE html>` added to the top of the page already.

Comment: What browser are you using? Your css is fine and it works in browsers I tried.

Comment: Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UR4XB/). Works as expected for me.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? Control-shift-delete/Command-shift/delete

Comment: @MBozic thanks for your reply, i have tried this is Chrome and Firefox both but same problem in both the browsers, it is a wordpress theme btw.

Comment: did you try clearing your browser's Cache?

Comment: I have Emptied the cache from both the browsers, tried but same result, when i make any other changes and refresh they appear immediately so i think it is not the cache.

Comment: it is strange that it is working as i want in the fiddle @maenu made in the same browser, can it be a wordpress issue ?

Comment: do you have any other CSS in you page CSS file? It might be overriding this CSS.

Comment: @Virendra i do have other CSS in the file but they do not include the navigation part at all. Moreover, if the CSS is being overridden it still shows in firebug and chrome inspection as overlined styles.

Comment: I have had similar issues earlier when some other CSS was been applied and due to that the CSS with ">" didn't get applied, and hence not shown when inspecting. I would suggest try removing other CSS and check whether it is working or not. As everyone else said the code you pasted works, so I think this being a possible reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the HTML example you provided is the full piece of code that you're trying to apply these styles to, I don't see how there could be any conflicts occurring to warrant using the direct descendant selector (>).

Just use the child selector for the whole thing.

```
/* Navigation */  
#navigation {
    min-height:45px;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 45px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #F3F3F3;
}

#navigation ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 18px 13px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#navigation ul li.current_page_item a, 
#navigation ul li.current_page_parent a, 
#navigation ul li.current_page_ancestor a {
    border-top: 3px solid #72AC4B;
    color: #72AC4B;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: No, `>` is the child selector. "direct descendant" is just another name for it; they both mean the same thing. The space is the descendant selector.

Comment: Sorry, got the terminology mixed up, but the pooint still stands.

Comment: Thanks @Nw167 . Though i figured out that the cms i was working on was actually wrapping the `ul` with a `div` element and so `ul` was not the direct children of the parent div anymore and that is why the styles were not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have replaced the "display : block" by "display : none" and the style does apply on firefox.
The question is on line-height, what are you trying to achieve as final design ?
Try changing the padding or margin it you want less space.

If that is not the problem can you place maybe give us an example of the end result you are seeking ??

Comment: as @maenu already made a fiddle and it works perfect i don't think it is to do with the style part at all, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/UR4XB/